# Nalgerba, how is the axis angle represented for a unit quaternion?

Tags: rust, rotation, quaternions, nalgebra

The [docs](https://docs.rs/nalgebra/0.8.2/nalgebra/struct.UnitQuaternion.html) for nalgebra say

```
fn new(axisangle: Vector3<N>) -> UnitQuaternion<N>[−]
Creates a new unit quaternion from the axis-angle representation of a rotation.
```

That's great, except, that's not an axis angle, that's just an axis. Most axis angle representations have an explicit angle and axis. One could make the assumption that the angle is encoded as the vector length, but I can;t find anything that explicitly says so.

Comment: If you look a [newer docs](https://docs.rs/nalgebra/latest/nalgebra/geometry/type.UnitQuaternion.html#method.new) you'll find a better description. The docs you linked are really old.

Comment: Oh I see I wonder why my search engine yielded the old docs as the first result.

Comment: That happens often. That's why the "Go to latest version" button on the top left is big and orange.